# Ansible conditional handlers for a task?

Tags: ansible

FYI, I'm running my Ansible playbook in "pull-mode" not push mode. Therefore, my nodes will publish the results of their task via Hipchat.

With that said, I have a task that installs RPMs. When the installs are successful, the nodes notify via Hipchat that the task was successfully run. Now, in the event that a task fails, i force it to notify hipchat w/ the "--force-handlers" paramter. My question, is there a way to call a particular handler depending on the outcome of the task?

## Task

```
- name: Install Perl modules
  command: sudo rpm -Uvh {{ rpm_repository }}/{{ item.key }}-{{ item.value.svn_tag }}.rpm --force
  with_dict: deploy_modules_perl
  notify: announce_hipchat
```

## Handler

```
- name: announce_hipchat
  local_action: hipchat
        from="deployment"
        token={{ hipchat_auth_token }}
        room={{ hipchat_room }}
        msg="[{{ ansible_hostname }}] Successfully installed RPMs!"
        validate_certs="no"
```

Comment: You can use 'when', 'with_items', etc. in your handlers.  Would conditionals give you what you want?  From your explaination and example code I'm not quite sure what you're looking to do...

Comment: This section of the docs might help: https://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_error_handling.html#ignoring-failed-commands You could ignore the failure and then do different things depending on whether it failed or succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I use multiple handlers. See following example :

> file *site.yml*

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  force_handlers: true
  vars:
  - cmds:
      echo: hello
      eccho: hello
  tasks:
  - name: echo
    command: "{{ item.key }} {{ item.value }}"
    register: command_result
    with_dict: "{{ cmds }}"
    changed_when: true
    failed_when: false
    notify:
    - "hipchat"
  handlers:
  - name: "hipchat"
    command: "/bin/true"
    notify:
    - "hipchat_succeeded"
    - "hipchat_failed"
  - name: "hipchat_succeeded"
    debug:
      var: "{{ item }}"
    with_items: "{{ command_result.results | selectattr('rc', 'equalto', 0) | list }}"
  - name: "hipchat_failed"
    debug:
      var: "{{ item }}"
    with_items: "{{ command_result.results | rejectattr('rc', 'equalto', 0) | list }}"
```

Use command

```
ansible-playbook -c local -i "localhost," site.yml
```

> CAUTION: use test filter ['equalsto'](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#equalto) added in jinja2 **2.8**